# ajdnik/homebrew-decrypo does not exist! Run `brew untap ajdnik/homebrew-decrypo` to remove it

Tags: mac-osx, mac

Whenever I do `brew update` in my local machine I get the below error

```
BOSM0001-RANATA:~ rajkumar.natarajan$ brew update
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/ajdnik/homebrew-decrypo/' not found

Error: ajdnik/homebrew-decrypo does not exist! Run `brew untap ajdnik/homebrew-decrypo` to remove it.
BOSM0001-RANATA:~ rajkumar.natarajan$ brew untap ajdnik/homebrew-decrypo
Error: Refusing to untap ajdnik/decrypo because it contains the following installed formulae or casks:
decrypo

BOSM0001-RANATA:~ rajkumar.natarajan$ brew untap decrypo
Error: Invalid tap name 'decrypo'
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that https://github.com/ajdnik/homebrew-decrypo/ appears to no longer exist.  You can try tapping https://github.com/avinash122186/homebrew-decrypo and installing decrypo from there.  I'm not on a Mac right now, so I can't confirm that will work.

If you don't use or need decrypo, uninstall it first, then run: `brew untap ajdnik/homebrew-decrypo`

If you do need it make a backup or perhaps a more advanced user can help.